# retrofit error when fetching pretty print json from php

Tags: android

I write a simple program for fetching some json data and I hit by this error

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

I searched in stackoverflow and I didn't get the answer
but I figured out this error is because of "JSON_PRETTY_PRINT" code in json encode or the pre tag maybe
.
I changed this :

```
echo "<pre>".json_encode($row,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."</pre>";
```

to this :

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

and it worked. But the printed json is really messy and ugly. Do you have any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use retrofit library and probably you are sending an array but on parsing you parse it as an Object not an array, thats problem

Comment: I've never change my android side code . I just remove the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT and all things worked well